# Need some help understanding the formula for specific resistance when using 4 wire resistance testing

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

The formula I have found for determining specific resistance from the total resistance of an object, where s (the distance between the probes) is greater than the thickness of the object being measured,  is $$p= 2πs(V/I).$$

This dosent make sense to me, as I would think that if the distance between the probes was larger, the total resistance $V/I$ would be larger as well. Therefore, if using the above formula, wouldnt the specific resistance grow with an increased probe spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where your equation for specific resistance has come from.
The definition of the specific resistance or resistivity $\rho$ of a material is

$$\rho = \dfrac{RA}{L}$$ where $R$ is the resistance of a material of length $L$ and cross-sectional area $A$.

Doubling the length of the material would double its resistance and so the specific resistance would stay the same.

**Update**

In the reference that you provided the resistance between the two inner  probe tips is found to be $R = \dfrac{1}{2s} \dfrac{\rho}{2 \pi}$ where $s$ is the separation of the probes.

So as the separation of the probes increases the resistance decreases in proportion.
So in your final equation for resistivity $\rho = 2 \pi s \left ( \dfrac V I\right )$ the product $s \left ( \dfrac V I\right )= sR$ stays constant.

Comment: The paper I got this equation from is this one here:

Comment: http://www.cen.iitb.ac.in/slotbooking/RECEPIES/140_RECEPIES.pdf . This paper was linked when I asked about using the formula you provided, and I was told it wouldn't hold up in more complex 3d geometries